# Memory leak when calling Plotly.plot() in a loop (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, plotly

I posted this on the plotly forum as well, but that forum does not seem to be very active...

Hello everybody,

I am using plotly.js in a bigger Asp.Net Webforms application (telerik controls are used as well) and stumbled upon memory leaks (tested in IE11). I tried different things out and created a small example (See code bellow). In the code I create a histogram plot with 4000x4000 random data points and plot them 10 times in the loop (Press the “Replot Traces” Button). I would expect that the new plot()-call in the next iteration just “overrides” the plot of the iteration before. But the memory usage increases until I run out of memory...

Deleting the whole plot or calling the GC does not help (the memory decreases just a little bit).

Did anybody have similar problems and has an idea how to handle this. Is there a way to completely reset/clear plotly without reloading the whole page (because in my big application I am using Ajax and cannot reload the whole page everytime)?.

Thanks in advance!

```
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
  <div id="delete" style="margin-left:80px;">
      <button style="background: red;" onclick="deletePlot()">Delete/Purge</button>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-left:80px;">
      <button style="background: green;" onclick="plotAll()">Replot Traces</button>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-left:80px;">
      <button style="background: blue;" onclick="CallGC()">Call GC</button>
  </div>

    <script>
        function deletePlot(){
            Plotly.purge('myDiv');
        }

        function plotAll()
        {
            var n = 4000

            var s2dArray = '[';
            for (var i=0; i <n; i++)
            {
                s2dArray = s2dArray.concat('[');
                for (var j=0; j <n; j++)
                {
                    s2dArray = s2dArray.concat(Math.round((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
                    if(j < n-1)
                    {
                        s2dArray = s2dArray.concat(',');
                    }
                }
                s2dArray = s2dArray.concat(']');
                if(i < n-1)
                {
                    s2dArray = s2dArray.concat(',');
                }
            }
            s2dArray = s2dArray.concat(']');

            var data = [
            {
                z: JSON.parse(s2dArray),
                type: 'heatmap'
                }
            ];

            for(var i =0; i<10; i++)
            {
                Plotly.plot('myDiv', data, {}, {showSendToCloud: true});
                console.log(i);
            }
        }

        function CallGC()
        {
            CollectGarbage();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```